# Android in app billing for shopping cart

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to use in-app billing for my eCommerce application, I want to buy 3 products at a time and its price is also dynamic, how can I implement it using  IN-APP BILLING android API? 
Dynamic product with dynamic price and want to buy multiple products at a time with offer price deduction

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial or do you have a specific problem?

Comment: Looking tutorial for how can i implement such functionality?

Comment: I am sorry, stackoverflow is not a place to ask for tutorials or recommendations.